# Distinct and order by issue in SQL query (Easy but is it possible?)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with these columns (MS SQL-Server 2008);

**city cityDate**

and rows like this;

- Porto | 20.11.1988
- Porto | 19.11.1988
- Lisbon | 21.11.1988

What I want is ordering the date column (desc) and getting the distinct values of city. So the resut should be;

- **Lisbon**
- **Porto**

I tried;

```
select distinct(city) from TableCity order by cityDate desc
```

but the output is;

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 ORDER BY items must appear in the
>   select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: but how, it doesnt make sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use group by instead of distinct:

Suppose T is your Table:

```
WITH T as
(
SELECT 'Porto' City,'20.11.1988' CityDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'Porto' City,'19.11.1988' CityDate UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lisbon' City,'21.11.1988' CityDate
)
```

--TEST 1:

```
select City,CityDate from T GROUP BY City,CityDate Order by CityDate DESC
```

--Result: This still displays the three rows because City Date of Porto is not the same,but if Porto City Date is the same it will display only two rows.

```
City    CityDate
Lisbon  21.11.1988
Porto   20.11.1988
Porto   19.11.1988
```

--TEST 2:

```
select T2.City 
FROM
(select City from T GROUP BY City,CityDate) as T2
GROUP BY T2.City
```

OR

you can use CTE:

```
With T as
(
select City from YourTable GROUP BY City,CityDate
)  

select City FROM T group by City
```

--Result:

```
City
Lisbon
Porto
```

Regards

Comment: no it is not working  'Column "TableCity.cityDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. '

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on my phone so the following is untested, but it should work

```
SELECT T2.city
FROM ( SELECT city, MAX(cityDate) AS maxDate
                   FROM T
                 GROUP BY city
                 ORDER BY maxDate desc ) AS T2
```